# Perl Behavioral Differences Closing Child Process Spawned with open() vs. IPC::Open3

Tags: perl

I'm trying to figure this out but haven't been able to wrap my head around it. I need to open a piped subprocess and read from its output. Originally I was using the standard open() call like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;

use warnings;
use strict;
use Scalar::Util qw(openhandle);
use IPC::Open3;

my $fname = "/var/log/file.log.1.gz";
my $pid = open(my $fh, "-|:encoding(UTF-8)", "gunzip -c \"$fname\" | tac");

# Read one line from the file
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    print "Row: $row\n";
    last; # Bail out early
}

# Check if the PID is valid and kill it if so
if (kill(0, $pid) == 1) {
    kill(15, $pid);
    waitpid($pid, 0);
    $pid = 0;
}

# Close the filehandle if it is still open
if (openhandle($fh)) {
    close $fh;
}
```

The above works, except that I get errors from tac in the logs saying:

```
tac: write error
```

From what I can tell from various testing and research that I've done, this is happening because killing the PID returned from open() just kills the first child process (but not the second) and so when I then close the filehandle, tac is still writing to it, thus the "write error" due to the broken pipe. The strange thing is, at times when I check ($? >> 8) if the close() call returns false, it will return 141, indicating it received a SIGPIPE (backing up my theory above). However, other times it returns 0 which is strange.

Furthermore, if I run the same command but without a double-pipe (only a single one), like this (everything else the same as above):

```
my $pid = open(my $fh, "-|:encoding(UTF-8)", "gunzip -c \"$fname\"");
```

...I'll get an error in the logs like this:

```
gzip: stdout: Broken pipe
```

...but in this case, gunzip/gzip was the only process (which I killed via the returned PID), so I'm not sure why it would still be writing to the pipe when I close the filehandle (since it was supposed to be killed already, AND waited for with waitpid()).

I'm trying to repro this in the Perl debugger but its difficult because I can't get the stderr of the child process with plain open() (the way I'm seeing the external process' stderr in prod is in the apache2 logs - this is a CGI script).

I understand from reading the docs that I can't get the PID of all child processes in a multi-piped open with open(), so I decided to try and resort to a different method so that I could close all processes cleanly. I tried open3(), and interestingly, without making any changes (literally running basically the same exact scenario as above but with open3() instead of open()):

```
my $pid = open3(my $in, my $fh, undef, "gunzip -c \"$fname\"");
```

...and then killing it just like I did above, I don't get any errors. This holds true for both the single piped process as shown above, as well as the double-piped process that involves piping to "tac".

Therefore, I'm wondering what I am missing here? I know there are differences in the way open() and open3() work, but are there differences in the way that child processes are spawned from them? In both cases I can see that the initial child (the PID returned) is itself a child of the Perl process. But its almost as if the process spawned by open(), is not getting properly killed and/or cleaned up (via waitpid()) while the same process spawned by open3() is, and that's the part I can't figure out.

And, more to the bigger picture and the issue at hand - what is the suggestion for the best way to cleanly close a multi-piped process in this sort of scenario? Am I spending more time than is warranted on this? The script itself works as it should aside from these errors, so if it turns out that the tac and gzip errors I'm seeing are inconsequential, should I just live with them and move on?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198931/discussion-on-question-by-dwillis77-perl-behavioral-differences-closing-child-pr).

Comment: @zdim - To your earlier point about how one open() method may be invoking a shell process and the other not - I think that might be exactly the reason for the differing behavior! I just looked closer and indeed, open() always invokes a shell (`sh -c gunzip -c [file]` in my case, which is a child of the Perl process itself and has a subprocess of `gzip -d -c [file]` under it), while open3() does not (it has `gzip -d -c [file]` as a direct subprocess of the Perl process when a single-piped command is invoked). With the double-pipe, a shell is invoked by both variations.

Comment: As @zdim says, it runs the command through a shell because perl is noticing that it contains shell metacharacters (the double quotes). You can kill the shell process and all its children (the process group) passing to `kill` the pid number negated as in `kill 15, -$pid`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to `waitpid` on a process created as a pipe. Perl will do it for you from the `close` call anyway.

Comment: @salva - Thanks for the clarification; unfortunately, the negative PID method didn't work either. But the negative signal DID work when I ran it on the parent Perl process. So it would seem the subprocesses are in the same process group with that?

Comment: "_the subprocesses are in the same process group_"  -- the shell that  perl starts will fork off what it needs to run the given pipeline, and those new processes are in the [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) with the shell that started them. To oversimplify things, a signal to the process group leader with the negated signal number goes to all processes in the group, which is why I suggested to try that.  However, you are right that the shell is _not_ a process group leader but the perl script is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because either your perl script or its parent is ignoring the `SIGPIPE` signal, and the ignore signal dispositions are inherited by the children.

Here is a simpler testcase for your condition:

```
$ perl -e '$SIG{PIPE}="IGNORE"; open my $fh, "-|", "seq 100000 | tac; true"; print scalar <$fh>'
100000
tac: write error
$ (trap "" PIPE; perl -e 'open my $fh, "-|", "seq 100000 | tac"; print scalar <$fh>')
100000
tac: write error
$ (trap "" PIPE; perl -e 'my $pid = open my $fh, "-|", "seq 100000 | tac"; print scalar <$fh>; kill 15, $pid; waitpid $pid, 0')
100000
$ tac: write error
```

The latter version does the same `kill` as the version from the OP, which will not kill either the right or left side of the pipeline, but the shell running and waiting for both (some shells will exec through the left side of a pipeline; with such shells, a `; exit $?` could be appended to the command in order to reproduce the example).

A case where `SIGPIPE` is ignored upon entering a `perl` script is when run via `fastcgi` -- which sets the `SIGPIPE` disposition to [ignore](https://github.com/FastCGI-Archives/mod_fastcgi/blob/48cb8e51411856d62a2d45d412a1158fcdfa6805/fcgi_pm.c#L428), and [expects](https://fastcgi-archives.github.io/FastCGI_FAQ.html#Signals) the script to handle it. In that case simply setting an `SIGPIPE` handler instead of `IGNORE` (even an empty handler) would work, since in that case the signal disposition will be reset to default upon executing external commands:

```
$SIG{PIPE} = sub { };
open my $fh, '-|', 'trap - PIPE; ... | tac';
```

When run as a standalone script it could be some setup bug (I've see it happen in questions related to containerization on Linux), or someone trying to exploit buggy programs running with elevated privileges not bothering to handle `write(2)` errors (`EPIPE` in this case).

> `my $pid = open3(my $in, my $fh, undef, "gunzip -c \"$fname\"");`
>
> ...and then killing it just like I did above, I don't get any errors.

Where should you get the errors from, if you're redirecting its stderr to the same `$fh` you only read the first line from?

The thing is absolutely no different with `open3`:

```
$ (trap "" PIPE; perl -MIPC::Open3 -e 'my $pid = open3 my $in, my $out, my $err, "seq 100000 | tac 2>/dev/tty"; print scalar <$out>')
100000
$ tac: write error
```

Comment: Hrmm, I must have misunderstood the open3() documentation. As in the example [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=419919) (and also in the IPC::Open3 docs), it is mentioned that if \*ERROR is false, it uses the same filehandle as stdout. In Perl, undef is one of the values that will eval to false, right? EDIT/UPDATE: Ok, I get it, yes reading one line from stdout we would not see the error if it was there. I missed that one.

Comment: Yes, I've already corrected that, though it doesn't change anything to the idea, really. You'll have to read the error message from `$fh`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, its starting to become clearer. I was able to confirm though that there is some difference in the way open() and open3() spawn processes (see my comment above or the chat the convo was moved to). I did not mess with the `SIGPIPE` handling at all (at least not to my knowledge). But this is a CGI script running from a webpage. You say that Perl's parent would have been the one to affect this. Is it possible that apache was the one causing the process(es) to ignore the received `SIGPIPE`?

Comment: Because if I remember correctly (I will readjust my script to confirm) I believe I got the same errors  in the logs back when I was just closing the filehandle and doing nothing else (as suggested here). Hence the reason I went on this hunt in the first place.

Comment: Maybe not apache but fastcgi or similar. I will test it when I got a machine where I could run that. My objections to the kill/wait danse weren't directly related to the gist of the problem, so I'll remove the last paragraph from the answer (I do hope you did get my point in the comments)

Comment: All of the `open -|`, `open |-`, `system`, `open2`, `open3`, etc will run the `command` by passing it to `/bin/sh -c` unless the command is passed as a list or it doesn't contain any shell metacharacters. Using anything like a pipeline completely precludes either.

Comment: Sure, no worries. That makes sense about the commands - the open3() command that didn't invoke the `sh -c` had no pipes or special chars (`gunzip` only, without `tac`), whereas the same command with open() would have a pipe (`-|`). Lots of useful info provided here, and your answer does explain what is going on (although I'd still like to wrap my head around exactly _why_ the process is ignoring the `SIGPIPE`), so I'm accepting this as the answer. Thanks for taking the time to explain this stuff (I'm still fairly new to Perl as you can probably tell - this is my first sizeable project in it).

Comment: @dwillis77 I have confirmed that fastcgi (and not apache) is setting `SIGPIPE` to "ignore", and updated the answer. I've also removed some misinformation, especially the quick-n-dirty fix, which didn't work with a standard-compliant `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Thanks for all your info - it really put me on the right track. I think I finally did figure out why its ignoring the `SIGPIPE` - I'm not using fastcgi _but_ I am using mod_cgid and we can see right in the mod_cgid.c source for my version (2.4.18) that it says in a comment `Note that we already ignore SIGPIPE in the core server`. So it would appear that it is indeed ignoring it, thus causing the situation you described. Thanks again - never would have figured this out without the info here.

Comment: And, just to confirm for any future readers - setting the `SIGPIPE` disposition back to the default manually in my code did resolve the issue (and then just closing the filehandle with `close()` and letting Perl clean up the piped processes). It seems either an empty handler (as noted by mosvy in the answer) or also just a `$SIG{PIPE} = "DEFAULT";` will work to accomplish this as well. Thanks again to all who responded.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to read the last line of a gzipped file, it's easy to do it in pure perl without calling an external program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw/$GunzipError/;

my $fname = 'foo.txt.gz';
my $z = new IO::Uncompress::Gunzip $fname or die "Couldn't open file: $GunzipError\n";
my $row;
while (<$z>) {
  $row = $_;
}
say "Row: $row";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shawn! Unfortunately, I do need to do a lot more with these files than just read the first or last line - I just used that as the simplest example of where I had noticed the issue with the piped processes. But my app as a whole is doing some heavy processing of some very large files, and so for performance reasons I decided to go with gzip and tac as opposed to the Perl modules to do the same, as they seemed to be much faster for this type of workload (at least based on the info I gathered when I started the project).

Comment: @dwillis77 Considering that when `tac`'s standard input is a pipe and not a file it has to read everything into memory before it can start printing out lines in reverse order, using it on the output of gunzipping a large file seems unlikely to be better than just doing your processing entirely in perl.

Comment: Interesting point... I wouldn't mind giving the Perl module in your example a shot to compare decompression performance. I mainly had researched the ReadBackwards one when comparing to tac previously - I did not compare the module you mentioned to g(un)zip.

Comment: However, I'm not sure that it has to read 100% of the file into memory before it can start printing out lines from the end because I just did a query against a gzip'd file backwards (9GB uncompressed, only 305MB(!) compressed), on a box with only 4GB RAM total, and it came back in just over a minute (with 1K results, which was the cap I set) with memory usage only hovering around 1.4GB during the search and no swap usage (CPU was ramped up during the search obviously, but not memory).

Comment: @dwillis77 `tac` is not reading the whole thing in the memory; it's using a temporary file and is reading it by seeking backwards from its end (strace it if you don't believe me). This answer of "write the whole thing in perl" would be much better if it included a tac implementation in `perl` which doesn't try to load the whole file in the memory, which doesn't sound like rocket science, but would better be the subject of another Q). Or if it pointed to a ready made module doing it.

Comment: Makes sense; that explains the behavior I saw with memory usage not capped. So the File::ReadBackwards Perl module _does_ load the whole thing in memory then in order to read it backwards?

Comment: @mosvy Which `tac` implementation is this? The [bsd ones](https://github.com/IIJ-NetBSD/netbsd-src/blob/master/usr.bin/tail/reverse.c) I checked sure don't do anything with temporary files.

Comment: The [`tac` from GNU coreutils](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tac.c?id=f2dfea7e99b36961530035750e72e80c41b83542#n542). What that bsd implemetation does is really broken; they should better refuse non-seekable files outright instead of buffering them in memory.

Comment: Re "*So the File::ReadBackwards Perl module does load the whole thing in memory then in order to read it backwards?*", No, it reads from the end in the exact same manner as a file is read from the start: Read a chunk, look for lines in the chunk, and read other chunks when needed. (As such, it requires a seekable file.)

Comment: Hmm. Was just wondering since the previous comment implied that the Perl modules written to do the same, _did_ try to load the whole file in memory. In any case, I will benchmark current versions of Perl modules doing these tasks against my current setup just to know for sure, because I am interested. But so far `tac` has proved quite efficient tbh.